# How to increase and decrease the height of the gridlines in advanced accessible highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using advanced accessible high charts and I need to be able to increase and decrease the height of gridlines based on the data points for a particular series. If the data points  for a particular series is less than 10 I want the height of the gridline to be 30 px else if the data points is between 10 and 15 I want the height to be 50px if the data points are more than 20 i will need the gridline height to be 100px

[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor?

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel - pls find the link with the example https://jsfiddle.net/Vinay_10/vc8hrx6s/58/  . Customer is very particular about the space between gridlines . The second series from the top has just one data point in the graph (provided in the link) hence space should be reduced compared to other series. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that came to my mind is to attach each series into an independent axis which allows setting each axis height (in percentage or pixel value).

```
  xAxis: [{
    height: '30%',
  }, {
    height: '60%',
    top: '30%',
    offset: 0
  }, {
    top: '80%',
    height: '10%',
    offset: 0
  }],

  series: [{
    data: [2, 3, 4],
    xAxis: 0
  }, {
    data: [10, 12],
    xAxis: 1
  }, {
    data: [10, 12],
    xAxis: 2
  }]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8pu13s7d/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.height

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.top

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Wedzel : Thanks for suggesting the answer . I tried to add the solution which you specified but it didn't seem to work I will have 500 to 1000 series(say serNo1....... serNo1000) and I can't manually assign the height and top for the axis lines/labels . It will have to be dynamically applied. How can it be done dynamically? Note : I am using a inverted graph

Comment: @VinayKumar in the demo that you shared you have defined 4 categories for xAxis - as I understand you would like to be able to set their height, so you need to add each category as a separate xAxis which allows you to customize their height

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Wedzel- Pls open the link https://jsfiddle.net/Vinay_10/vc8hrx6s/61/ that contains my code . I tried separate axis for each but it adds a different axis on its own to the left of the existing axis but its not making any changes to the existing graph . Could you pls modify this and try. (Note: I am using advanced accessible graph and not a bar graph . It is inverted)

Comment: @VinayKumar after digging more into your code I realized that points in the series are assigned to each category, not to the particular one, so if you want to use this solution you will need to change your data structure - render each point as a separate series. Btw, why don't you use the columnrange series, but implement a custom one? You will be able to create something similar much simpler: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/07ckbg2h/